# I uninstalled Ubuntu 18.04LTS and installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS on windows 10, but now it is not working with virtual environment

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, uninstall, windows-10, 20.04

[I uninstalled **Ubuntu 18.04LTS** and installed **Ubuntu 20.04LTS** on *windows 10* but it is not working correctly with `python3 -m venv env` when I create a virtual environment, also it does not work with already created environments **error is** ```The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

```
apt-get install python3-venv
```

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/mnt/e/CS50/web/practice/test/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']```]

Comment: You forgot to use 'sudo'

Answer (score 0):

Pretty obvious but have you tried sudo?

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks now the virtual environment is not being created, can you tell me what's wrong with it

Comment: "X didn't work" is much too vague to  offer advice upon, and not related to the lack of 'sudo' that is your original question. AskUbuntu is a Question/Answer site not an interactive forum. Please open a detailed new question about your current problem.

Comment: I can't get much information out of your comment, nevertheless I've seen your edit and perhaps you could try to reinstall venv {sudo apt-get reinstall python-venv} and then recreate the virtual environment {rm -rf venv} and then {sudo apt install python3.8-venv}